# How to I use TryParse in a linq query of xml data?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm working with in memory xml of daily stock market data, and I'm getting the value "8/221/19055" for one of the dates. I see that TryParse is likely my best bet to check for a valid date, but the MSDN doc seems light on an explanation of the 2nd parameter "out DateTime result." How can I use it in my linq query below?

```
var makeInfo =
         from s in doc.Descendants("quote")
         where s.Element("LastTradeDate") != null
                && s.Attribute("symbol") != null
         let dateStr = s.Element("LastTradeDate").Value
         where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateStr)
                && DateTime.Parse(dateStr, enUS) == targetDate
         select new DailyPricingVolDP((string)s.Attribute("symbol"),
                                      (DateTime)s.Element("LastTradeDate"),
                                      (double)s.Element("Open"),
                                      (double)s.Element("DaysHigh"),
                                      (double)s.Element("DaysLow"),  
                                      (double)s.Element("LastTradePriceOnly"),
                                       (long)s.Element("Volume"));
```

Comment: have u tried to save that output into a variable first, then compare the 2 dates in ur linq to xml

Comment: @Boomer Thanks, it looks like that (or some form of that logic) will be the solution, going through these now..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Func<string, DateTime?> tryToGetDate =
        value =>
            {
                DateTime dateValue;
                return DateTime.TryParse(value, out dateValue) ? (DateTime?) dateValue : null;
            };

    var makeInfo =
         from s in doc.Descendants("quote")
         where s.Element("LastTradeDate") != null
                && s.Attribute("symbol") != null
         let dateStr = s.Element("LastTradeDate").Value
         let dateValue = tryToGetDate(dateStr)
         where dateValue != null && (DateTime)dateValue == targetDate
         select .... etc etc
```

Comment: Thanks.. that looks to be the most straight forward to implement the way I have things structured.

Comment: One point looking at this again is that you dont need the try parse at all. Just use the HasValue:

Comment: where s.Element("LastTradeDate").HasValue && where s.Element("LastTradeDate") == targetDate     I think this would do it so you can loose the let values in the query

Comment: Nullable<T>.HasValue would work. Like: ... where dateValue.HasValue && dateValue.Value == targetDate

Comment: @Andy I'm working on implementing your fix now, thx for introducing me to Func type.

Answer (score 4):

To eliminate `out` parameter of `TryParse` you can abstract entire parsing in the generic delegate like standard `Converter<TInput, TOutput>`:

```
Converter<string, DateTime> converter = (str) =>
                {
                    DateTime dateTime;
                    if (!DateTime.TryParse(str, out dateTime))
                    {
                       // custom business logic for such cases
                       dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
                    }

                    return dateTime;
                };
```

or in case you need passing in more parameters use `Func<string, string, DateTime>`, it is up to you, implementation (string to date parsing logic) is up to you as well.

Then use in the query:

```
converter(rawString) == targetDate
```

Comment: What will that do when you pass "8/221/19055" into it (as str)?

Comment: This is just an idea abstracting TryParse by generic delegate to eliminate out parameter. You can extend is passing more parameters using `Func<>` and analyzing parsing issues considering your business logic

Answer (score 1):

```
Datetime somedate;

if(DateTime.TryParse(datetotest, out somedate)
{

     code for using date goes here

}
```

Comment: Thanks... I'm new to linq, so I'm not sure how to incorporate that into my var= statement though.

Answer (score 1):

It could be refactored to something like this with no need for functions and a simpler query which does the same job:

```
var makeInfo = from s in doc.Descendants("quote")
    where s.Attribute("symbol").HasValue 
    && s.Element("LastTradeDate").HasValue 
    && DateTime.Parse(Element("LastTradeDate").Value) == targetDate
    select .... etc etc
```

Comment: Do you mean that's the whole lot of it, including checking for the erroneous date value?

Comment: Does your xml have a schema which it is validate against stating that LastTradeDate is a date in which case you know it will be a valid date?